# Updating dataframe in R for each observation where condition occurs transform to 2 rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following input dataframe.
For all cases where C3 is <->, @->, or <-@ I want to create two new rows for each instance where this occurs. The two new rows will contain the original C1 and C2 as C1 and update C2 as L1 or L2 or L3 or so on..depending on each time it occurs. C3 becomes updated to ->. Hope this makes sense.. How can I do this?

Input:

```
         C1         C2    C3
1         A          D   <-> 
2         G          D   @-> 
3         K          A   @-> 
4         K          Q    ->
```

Expected Output:

```
         C1         C2    C3
1         A         L1    <-
2         D         L1    <- 
3         G         L2    <-
4         D         L2    <- 
5         K         L3    <-
6         A         L3    <- 
7         K          Q    ->
```

To be more clear row 1 in the input transforms to rows 1 and 2 in the expected output, row 2 in input transforms to rows 3 and 4 in output, row 3 in input transforms to rows 5 and 6 in output. And row 4 in input remains unchanged and becomes row 7 in expected output.

EDIT: can i do this with a pivot function in dplyr?

Comment: Why is row 8 missing in the expect output? Is it because `->` should do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a try how it may work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(C1, C2)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(group = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n()))) %>% 
  mutate(C3 = ifelse(C3 %in% c("<->", "@->"), "<-", "->")) %>% 
  select(C1=value, C2=name, C3, group) %>% 
  mutate(C2 = case_when(C3 == "->" ~last(C1),
                        C3 == "<-" ~paste0("L", group))) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(C3 == "->" & row_number()==2, NA, .))) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group)
```

```
  C1    C2    C3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     L1    <-   
2 D     L1    <-   
3 G     L2    <-   
4 D     L2    <-   
5 K     L3    <-   
6 A     L3    <-   
7 K     Q     ->
```